# From where can I find "Great programming quotes" question?

Tags: support, questions

Actually, I marked this question and similar to this as a favorite question on SO. However, now I cannot find them. Were such questions deleted or moved somewhere else?
Previously, it was here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58640/great-programming-quotes but now it's giving page not found.

Comment: http://www.stackprinter.com/questions/great-programming-quotes.html

Comment: I saved it (minor cleanup performed), just to be sure it's not lost https://gist.github.com/1875572

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, the page you now see says:

> This question was removed from Stack Overflow for reasons of moderation. Please refer to the FAQ for **[possible explanations why a question might be removed](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion)**.

So yes, the question was both closed and deleted because it is neither a valid question, nor on topic for Stack Overflow. The [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask) clearly outlines what kinds of questions should not be asked, and this one fits squarely into several of those categories.

Users with 10k+ reputation can still view deleted questions, but with less than that, you're out of luck. Your only hope is if someone like Google has cached the contents. In general, you shouldn't bank on severely off-topic and nonconstructive questions sticking around for very long. If you're interested for whatever reason in the answers that have been posted, you should save them yourself.

Comment: True, but  unfortunate. This was the best collection of programming quotes on the web. Even though it was deleted, I regularly went there to look up quotes. Maybe questions with more than 1000 upvotes should not be permanently deleted?

Comment: What an absolute joke. A piece of internet history destroyed by jobsworths. Great work mods

Comment: "A piece of internet history"? What *isn't* Internet history? Does that make everything sacred?

Answer (score 3):

You can still view this question via The Internet Archive's [WaybackMachine](http://archive.org/web/web.php).

http://web.archive.org/web/20100818203850/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58640/great-programming-quotes

This is a snapshot of the page as it existed on August 18th 2010.